# How to preview the file attached in the ContentVersion

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, files

We have a requirement to preview the related file in the lwc component. Something which is similar to a modal dialog which displays the file if it is a known format to the browser (like pdf or jpg).

I am aware that the file is linked via contentLink and then all the way to contentVersion.

But when I navigate through the fields of contentLink, it doesn't seem to me there is a field for this purpose.

VersionData field is a link which can be used in workbench but doesn't seem to be able to directly open that in an url.

ContentUrl fields are empty for all my files in my current org.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative url "/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/contentversionid" All you need is content version Id .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava is there a version for preview instead of download?

Comment: I think if you put that in an image tag it does get you a preview

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Sorry, I might have been stupid here. But I still didn't quite catch that. How should I put an image tag? By changing the download in the link to be image?

Comment: I thought you can simply put url in html image tag using src attribute. Anyways i think the one that i have in answer might be more straight forward and a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are is native approach documented by salesforce

**Use native navigationmixin for file preview.**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_open_files

> The navigation service opens the preview of one or more files in a modal dialog in Lightning Experience, or triggers a file download in the Salesforce app on mobile devices.

Example in your case it would be as below

```
<!-- openFileSample.html -->
<template>
 <div>
   <a onclick={navigateToFiles}>Navigate To File</a>
 </div>
</template>
```

JS Code

```
// openFileSample.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

 export default class OpenFileSample extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

navigateToFiles() {
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: 'filePreview'
    },
    state : {
        selectedRecordId:'contentDocumentId'
     }
   })
  }

}
```

ContentDocumentId can be obtained by querying ContentVersion Object.